# Install Codendi on CentOS

Tags: virtualbox, centos

I want to manage my project using project management software. After reading about Codendi, I try to install [Codendi](http://www.codendi.com/index_en.PHP) 4.2.3.10 on CentOS 5.6 using VirtualBox 4.0.2.

Here's the situation:

1. I'm totally noobs about Linux, so I'm using this guide to install CentOS: http://paulsiu.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/creating-and-managing-centos-virtual-machine-under-VirtualBox/
2. After CentOS installed sucessfullly, I try to mount codendi image and run the installer from terminal.
3. The installer said that I've some package that is not installed yet, so I do some yum install for the other packages.
4. Run the Codendi installer again, input some settings for password, company name, and IP.
5. Reboot CentOS.
6. Start mysql and PHP, and run codendi in Firefox using [specified IP]/[folder name].
7. Browser said that the Connection is time out.

I don't know where the problem is, is there any wrong step I do before or else. Please help me, or maybe you can suggest me another good project management software that is easy to install.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so it doesn't really belong on http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can try another project management application such as Redmine or Project Pier that more easier to install.